# Why does my postgresql custom type constructor produce ERROR: type is only a shell?

Tags: postgresql

I created a timerange type with the below. At least I thought I did, my local version might have been created through a `pg_restore` operation.

```
CREATE TYPE timerange AS RANGE (
    subtype = TIME
);
```

If I try to create a new timerange with `SELECT timerange('23:00'::TIME, '23:30'::TIME)` I get

```
ERROR:  type "timerange" is only a shell
```

How can my timeranges lead a fulfilling life?

Comment: [Works for me...](http://rextester.com/ACG68266) Try re-running your `CREATE TYPE` statement.

Comment: @NickBarnes, yeah, I did get it to work by dropping and recreating. Just confused how this error appeared, and how to try to prevent it in the future.

Comment: You get a shell type by running `CREATE TYPE timerange;` without supplying a definition. I suppose `pg_restore` might have done this, though I couldn't say why (and unless it crashed half-way through, it should have eventually cleaned it up).

Comment: @NickBarnes ah. I may have accidentally just copied the `FUNCTION` definition in pgAdmin and run that rather than the `CREATE TYPE [...]` from the question. Boo pgAdmin for not showing custom types. Feel free to post your comment as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using pgAdmin3 when this problem happened. pgAdmin3 doesn't display custom types (pgAdmin4 does). In performing a backup or just copying and pasting stuff from one server to another the `FUNCTION` of this type was created, e.g.:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.timerange(
    time without time zone,
    time without time zone)
  RETURNS timerange AS
'range_constructor2'
  LANGUAGE internal IMMUTABLE
  COST 1;
```

Anyways, performing a `DROP TYPE timerange;` query and then re-running the query above was successful.